# appending new values to a Datafram element which is of type list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to match `Sample ID`s to a list of `tissue_names`. One `Sample ID` could have more than one tissue. Hence, I have created an empty array initially and want to add the tissue names to `tissue_name` column below.

```
TCGA_luad['tissue_name'] = 'NA'
for index, row in TCGA_luad.iterrows():
    for item in TCGA_lung_tissue_names:
        if row['Sample ID'] in item:
            if row['tissue_name'] == 'NA':
                TCGA_luad.at[index, 'tissue_name'] = []
                TCGA_luad.at[index, 'tissue_name'].append(item)
            else:
                print('here')
                TCGA_luad.at[index, 'tissue_name'].append(item)
```

While I have more than one Tissue Name for many of the cases belonging to the same Sample ID, it never goes to the second part of else, and 'here' doesn't get printed.

However, the tissue names doesn't get appended and I get all items as `[]`. Do you know why the append doesn't work?

```
/tmp/ipykernel_2331339/2964965853.py:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  TCGA_luad['tissue_name'] = 'NA'
```

I end up with all of `tissue_name` column being `[]`

[image]

```
len(TCGA_lung_tissue_names)
3206

TCGA_lung_tissue_names[:3]
['TCGA-05-4244-01A-01-BS1',
 'TCGA-05-4244-01A-01-TS1',
 'TCGA-05-4244-01Z-00-DX1']
```

Comment: Will you please provide a sample of `TCGA_lung_tissue_names`? and also the rest of your df?

Comment: @richardec updated. Please check end of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best solution, but the following worked:

```
TCGA_luad['tissue_name'] = 'NA'

duplicates = {}

for index, row in TCGA_luad.iterrows():
    duplicate_counter = 0
    duplicates[row['Patient ID']] = []
    for item in TCGA_lung_tissue_names:
        if row['Patient ID'] in item:
            if row['Sample ID'] in item:
                duplicate_counter += 1
                duplicates[row['Patient ID']].append(item)
                if row['tissue_name'] == 'NA':
                    TCGA_luad.at[index, 'tissue_name'] = []
    TCGA_luad.at[index, 'tissue_name'] = duplicates[row['Patient ID']]
                
    if duplicate_counter > 1:
        print(duplicate_counter)
```

Comment: Just as some friendly feedback on your question, it would have been helpful (and perhaps still would be) to understand what your TCGA_luad dataframe looked like, including its 'Sample ID' values and any relationship between 'Sample ID', 'Patient ID' and 'tissue_name'.

Comment: Patient ID is in Sample ID and Sample ID is in tissue_name

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple `apply` statement will be easier to understand, shorter, and possibly more performant:

```
df['tissue_name'] = df['Sample ID'].apply(lambda sid: [item for item in TCGA_lung_tissue_names if sid in item] or 'NA')
```